# Some chars encoded during POST while others are not

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, xss, html-encode

### TL;DR

CodeIgniters' [Security](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/security.html) Class directly manipulates your Globals such as `$_POST` and it finds `file()` and `file ()` to be a threat so it HTML encodes it.

```
// config.php from my apps folder is the culprit
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

**Do-It-Yourself (the few, the brave)**

In CodeIgniter 2.1.4 go to `system/core/security.php` and line #430-442:

```
/*
* Sanitize naughty scripting elements
*
* Similar to above, only instead of looking for
* tags it looks for PHP and JavaScript commands
* that are disallowed.  Rather than removing the
* code, it simply converts the parenthesis to entities
* rendering the code un-executable.
*
* For example:  eval('some code')
* Becomes:      eval&#40;'some code'&#41;
*/

$str = preg_replace('#(alert|cmd|passthru|eval|exec|expression|system|fopen|fsockopen|file|file_get_contents|readfile|unlink)(\s*)\((.*?)\)#si', "\\1\\2&#40;\\3&#41;", $str);
```

### Observation/question

Basically, it seems as though either PHP or Apache sees `file ()` or `file()` as a threat.

Has anyone experienced this before or have documentation resources as to why this occurs?

Can anyone test this on their server to see if they experience the same behavior? I have tested this on both my Development and Testing machines. I have not had a chance to test on the Production machine because our clients connect to it.

### Code

**HTML**

```
<input name="q1" type="text" value="Profile (61) (D)">
<input name="q2" type="text" value="(61) (D)">
<input name="q3" type="text" value="file (61)">
<input name="q4" type="text" value="fil (61)">
<input name="q5" type="text" value="file ()">
<input name="q6" type="text" value="file()">
```

**JS - probably irrelevant**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/test_post'
    ,async: true
    ,cache: false
    ,type: 'POST'
    ,data: {
        q1: $('input[name="q1"]').val(),
        q2: $('input[name="q2"]').val(),
        q3: $('input[name="q3"]').val(),
        q4: $('input[name="q4"]').val(),
        q5: $('input[name="q5"]').val(),
        q6: $('input[name="q6"]').val()
    }
    ,dataType: 'json'
    ,success: function(data){
        console.log('irrelevant');
    }
});
```

**Network - Headers tab in Chrome - Form Data section**

```
q1: Profile (61) (D)
q2: (61) (D)
q3: file (61)
q4: fil (61)
q5: file ()
q6: file()
```

**PHP - CodeIgniter 2.1.4 Framework**

```
echo '<pre>'.$_POST['q1'].'</pre>'; // produces: Profile &#40;61&#41; (D)
echo '<pre>'.$_POST['q2'].'</pre>'; // produces: (61) (D)
echo '<pre>'.$_POST['q3'].'</pre>'; // produces: file &#40;61&#41;
echo '<pre>'.$_POST['q4'].'</pre>'; // produces: fil (61)
echo '<pre>'.$_POST['q5'].'</pre>'; // produces: file &#40;&#41;
echo '<pre>'.$_POST['q6'].'</pre>'; // produces: file&#40;&#41;

echo '<pre>'.html_entity_decode($_POST['q1']).'</pre>'; // produces: Profile (61) (D)
echo '<pre>'.html_entity_decode($_POST['q2']).'</pre>'; // produces: (61) (D)
echo '<pre>'.html_entity_decode($_POST['q3']).'</pre>'; // produces: file (61)
echo '<pre>'.html_entity_decode($_POST['q4']).'</pre>'; // produces: fil (61)
echo '<pre>'.html_entity_decode($_POST['q5']).'</pre>'; // produces: file ()
echo '<pre>'.html_entity_decode($_POST['q6']).'</pre>'; // produces: file()

// Both of these produce same exact result
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';
echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->input->post(), true).'</pre>';
```

### Browsers tested

- Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m
- IE 8
- FF 25.0

### Server Information

**Dev**

- Widnows 7 x64
- Apache 2.2.17
- PHP 5.3.5

**Testing**

- Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
- Apache 2.2.21
- PHP 5.3.8

Comment: It's very possible that `q1` and `q3` might be seen as potential maliciously intended function calls: `Profile (61)` could theoretically be that. So that's one reason I can think of, why this is happening.

Comment: @EduardLuca Thank you for the suggestion. I am using `q1` `q2` and `q3` for visual separation of the various combinations of text being POSTed. The symptoms get produced no matter which textfield receives a string with a matching `field ()` pattern.

Comment: I would say (at least going off your examples) that the pattern would be `anystring ()`. This (continuing my earlier idea) is due to the fact that both `Profile (61)` and `file (61)` (that's why `q1` and `q3` are encoded) can in theory be function calls, while `(61)` alone, can not (that's why `q2` is not encoded). Again, not sure if this is the reason why it's doing that, but it certainly would make sense.

Comment: @EduardLuca I have done more testing on my server, please review `q4` `q5` and `q6`. Please let me know if you would like to see something else.

Comment: Well, `q4` disproves my theory, so I got nothing else, sorry :) I still think it's security-related though.

Comment: @EduardLuca I certainly appreciate the effort and I think it is security related as well but I am not sure at which level. I initially thought the browser was doing something funky before posting but then I took a look at the `Networking` tab. My apologies for not fully understanding your first comment. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Have you tried the usage of filter_input: http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-input.php

Comment: @wegus I have not yet, I will read the documentation and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Do you have CodeIgniters [Security](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/security.html) module enabled globally?

Comment: @mabi wow my face is red right now. Config file reads `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`

Comment: @mabi I always thought the filtering gets applied through the `Input` class only upon calling a `POST` variable like this `$this->input->post('q1');` I didn't realize it alters the `$_POST` as well.

Comment: Tbh, I was staring at the user manual in disbelief for a couple of minutes.

Comment: @mabi Looks like I need to abide by `RTFM` from time to time lol :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/security.html), you can get rid of this by setting

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

Or just remove this line.

IMHO, it's a design failure to modify the `$_POST` array, but there you go.