# XSS Filtering in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, validation, codeigniter-2

I just want to ask because I'm currently new in codeginiter and based on the documentation shown on XSS Filtering, it says that:

```
By default it does not run globally since it requires a bit of processing overhead, 
and since you may not need it in all cases.
```

What this actually means? Because I setup xss filtering globally thru config.php:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

What does the documentation means on the downside on doing the above instead of doing this?

```
$this->security->xss_clean()
```

Comment: It can cause unintended issues as I have discovered because it directly modifies the `$_POST`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081165/some-chars-encoded-during-post-while-others-are-not

Answer (score 1):

[xss_clean()](http://docs.gipertext.com/framework/ci170/dc/d47/classCI__Input.html#39d5986d49a9d2d393c4a039b305fcea) is an extensive,  and is also silly.  90% of this function does nothing to prevent xss.  Such as looking for the word `alert`  but not `document.cookie`.  No hacker is going to use `alert` in their exploit,  they are going to hijack the cookie with xss or read a CSRF token to make an XHR.

However running `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` with it is just nothing but redundant.   A case where `xss_clean()` fixes the issue and `htmlentities($text, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')`  fails is the following:

```
<?php
print "<img src='$var'>";
?>
```

A simple poc is:

```
 http://localhost/xss.php?var=http://domain/some_image.gif'%20onload=alert(/xss/)
```

This will add the `onload=` event handler to the image tag.   A method of stoppipng this form of xss is `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES);`  or in this case `xss_clean()` will also prevent this.

However, quoting from the xss_clean() documentation:

> Nothing is ever 100% foolproof, of
>   course, but I haven't been able to get
>   anything passed the filter.

That being said,  XSS is an `output problem` **not** a `input problem`.  For instance this function cannot take into account that the variable is already within a `<script>` tag or event handler.   It also doesn't stop DOM Based XSS.  You need to take into consideration *how you are using the data* in order to use the best function.  Filtering all the data on input is a **bad practice**.   Not only is it insecure but it also corrupts data which can make comparisons difficult.

Comment: A bit more up to date reference of `xss_clean` https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Security.php#L321

Comment: its an Useful comment @ConnorTumbleson

Comment: what do you mean by output problem and input problem?

Comment: even that is mentioned in my answer.. Kindly read it thouroughly