# how to prevent conversion of %(number) to code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, percent-encoding

I have this line in PHP that is building a query parameter in PDO:

```
$p[':criteria'] = '%' . $search . '%';
```

The line of MySQL in question looks like this:

```
d.d_name LIKE :criteria
```

The problem is if I put a number in $search, it's converting it to a character. For example, if I set $search to:

```
6008
```

I want it to be:

```
%6008%
```

but what I get is:

```
`08%
```

It looks like it is %-encoding the 1st 2 characters. I tried using urldecode() to revert it, but it didn't work. It kept the string as `08%.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: "but what I get" --- but you get it where?

Comment: Are you using a framework, ORM, or any abstraction layer?

Comment: Neither PHP not PDO converts your data. It remains exactly the same. Thus there is not a single problem with your code.

Comment: More context needed: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f85d98c120b1ea1316d6041e826047a6b510f1ef

Comment: @ zerkms: In the resulting query.

Comment: I am using no framework, ORM, or abstraction layer.

Comment: "In the resulting query" --- no it does not. Mysql returns exactly the data you've put there.

Comment: @zerkms: :criteria is a token in the original query that's in an external file. The token will be replaced with the value passed in from PDO when the query runs. PDO automatically handles escaping the value when not using LIKE, but in this case it's not working as expected.

Comment: @raphael75 "PDO automatically handles escaping the value when not using LIKE, but in this case it's not working as expected." --- it does not. PDO does not do anything automagically, everything it does need to be stated explicitly.

Comment: @MarkBaker you were right in your comments. Have found the info you mentioned here: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php deleted the answer. I didn't knew the binding removed quotes. Thanks for pointing, and explaining it.

Comment: Because of thinks like that in the past (thing like the issue OP presents and the bind being 'smart' and then messing around variables) and although many don't like this aproach, I tend to validate all variables to avoid sql injection and concatenate a query in a string that I can debug and have more control about.

Comment: Let me ask this question. If I have this line in PHP: $search = '6008';$str = '%' . $search . '%';   How can I prevent it from %-encoding $str? It's seeing $str as %60 in hex, which evaluates to ` (reference: http://www.asciitable.com/), and then seeing 08% as the rest of the string.

Comment: To me the answer is: bind has to be generic by it's own nature. It's hard to avoid these cases. In this case I would not use bind and use a more controllable string, making a variable validation before.

Comment: @raphael75 encoding it by *what*? php does not do that for sure.

Comment: can you please post your complete code @raphael75 most probably there is an error in your syntax making $search not being escaped properly. That is why %60 is interpreted as `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind mecanism is too generic because it has to deal with many types and there are some edge cases like this.

So in this case, instead of using bind, mount your query as a string:

```
$sql = "...whatever d.d_name LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
```

Debug $search to be sure it doesn't have any quotes or anything before concatenating. If it has remove with trim or something like that.

Also be sure to validate $search correctly because of sql-injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an *illusion*. You are trying to watch your query using inappropriate tool, like a browser. And this tool does some conversion. Absolutely irrelevant to SQL stuff.

While for a database your query remains exactly the same. And there is not a single problem with any conversions. Just run your query and get the result.

Comment: I'd like to point out that OP is very likely using a framework of some sort and the `$_POST` data is being manipulated before it is ever assigned to `$search`. It's also possible that OP could have some unknown JS code doing something similar. [I've had an issue like this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081165/some-chars-encoded-during-post-while-others-are-not)

Answer (score -1):

I reccomend you to read about string escaping, it may help you on solving this problem, and alse good thing too know as some programming basics.